# Displaying link in popup with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup

I'm working with the Leaflet JavaScript library. There should be an option to click on my map and view a popup. I already have a code for that:

```
var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(e.latlng.toString() + "<br><b>Visit Google</b>")
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

This code is working, but my question is: how can i put an link to that popup? For example there should be  a link called "Visit Google". When you click on that link it should open www.google.com (*surprise*). I think it should be in the **`.setContent(e.latlng.toString())`** tag, because I can add there a text like **Visit Google** (as you can see).

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are providing html in setContent()

```
var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(e.latlng.toString() + '<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>"')
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :) I would vote your comment up, but my reputation score is too low :D

Comment: Now I was able to vote your comment up ;)