# How to add links to popups in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, html, mapbox-gl-js, hyperlink

I have managed to make a map w/ styled pops and such. However, what I am trying to do now is to have it such that the links inside of the popups connect directly to websites. If possible, I would like the title text (h3) of the popups to go directly to the websites when clicked.

I am a bit of a js/css/webmapping newbie.

Code:

```
    map.on('click', function(e) {
 var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
layers: ['masterdirectory-qc-v5-dyz490'] 
 });

 if (!features.length) {
return;
```

}

```
var feature = features[0];

 var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.Company + '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.City + '</p>' + feature.properties.URL + '</p>')
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.addTo(map);
```

});

My goal is to take all the URL's contained in the column referenced by feature.properties.URL and connect them to the title, retrieved by feature.properties.Company.

My research turned up [Display a link in a popup with Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111410) which seems to be a very similair question. I'm guessing my issue is less a problem understanding mapbox gl js and more a lack of knowledge about webdev in general.

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption in the last paragraph is actually true, because this has nothing to do with Mapbox GL JS, but only with basic HTML.

Basically you have to [define a link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) with the `<a>` tag inside your `<h3>` tag in the popup like this:

```
.setHTML('<h3><a href="' + feature.properties.URL + '">' + feature.properties.Company + '</a></h3>')
```

---

Comment: This is the actual line of code, it was missing a quote inside the end-parenthesis at the end (the last character). This was pointed out by user @TimRo in another answer below.

.setHTML('<h3><a href="' + feature.properties.URL + '">' + feature.properties.Company + '</a></h3>')

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

My only addition: the code in the answer is missing an `'` at the end. Took me a while to find it.

Here the adjusted code that worked for me

```
.setHTML('<h3><a href="' + feature.properties.URL + '">' + feature.properties.Company + '</a></h3>')
```

---

NOTE: This modification was added to the answer it is referring to, by @tallistroan

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!

I modified the answer by tallistroan to include the quote. It is very important that the original answer is correct.

Can you delete this answer?